# How to create project in workfront through api

Tags: rest, workfront-api

I will try this POST /attask/api/project?name=New Project ,But it give me unauthorized access error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either establish a session first using the API login function or you need to include an API key in your parameters. I personally like API key. Just add apiKey=your_api_key. You can find your API key under setup->System->Customer Info. You might need to generate one first if you haven't already created one.